# Exchange Rate API

Tags: google-app-engine

I am looking to create an application for exchange rate of foreign currencies and need backend for the same. While searching for the same, i came across:

http://rate-exchange.appspot.com

http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=1  //working demo

I also find the github source for this GAE project at:
https://github.com/hippasus/ExchangeRates

Now the question I have how should I proceed. Shall I use this already deployed project named http://rate-exchange.appspot.com or deploy my own version. If I should deploy my own version then what will be steps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have a question? If you are asking how to deploy, see here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading but if you are asking "should I use this or write my own?" how can anybody answer that except you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally try to use existing code with permission and visibly give credit to avoid plagiarism.  Developers who repeat work already done by others learn from the experience but risk wasting time unnecessarily.  You learn from others by studying their code anyway.

You may after some experience with the other project think of ways to improve it.  Liaise on Github with the original author about constructive collaboration.  Sharing code is what makes free and open source software great.

Comment: yes and probably I will contact the author directly for any enhancement. Thanks